# Stack Exchange "security" measures get tripped when using Tor and TBB

Tags: discussion, cloudflare

When browsing and searching `tor.stackexchange.com` I found myself hitting the Cloudflare wall and also infrequently having to select pictures of salad to identify myself as a person and not a robot.  What if I am indeed a robot?  Isn't that discriminatory?

All joking aside, isn't there some quantity of irony here that a Stack Exchange site revolving around the use of Tor and the Tor browser bundle constantly has its security mechanisms tripped if you use said software to access the site?

Also, I just got a warning that I could only post once a day "due to spam coming from my network."  Seriously? Like, seriously?

I understand that Cloudflare may offer the site operators uptime and security defenses, but due to the number of complaints/questions on this Stack Exchange dealing with Cloudflare's broken CAPTCHAs, something I came here to investigate as well, I don't think that is good form.

For those who haven't realized it yet, you can generate a new circuit to get through to the site, since the offending thing is an IP and the new circuit gives you a new IP to the Cloudflare site.  I have only gotten through 1 or 2 Cloudflare CAPTCHAs and been presented with many and wound up giving up on going to the site.  Some people claim that it requires scripts from Google, maybe that's why I never got it to work.

Comment: I asked a similar question several weeks ago: https://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/q/252/88 and never received an answer. I also tried to ask the mods via mail, but also this was ignored. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that proper solution for this situation will be the creation of hi-security HTTPS entrance for whole StackExchange network in Tor on dot-onion address. It will be right, because an existing infrastructure seems to be just fine, except weak HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

A question substantially similar to yours [was answered by another CM on the network meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231893/) a year and a half ago, and the answer there should apply here as well (although I imagine you won't like it). The most salient bit:

> don't use Tor ... Tor is a fine tool, but like any tool it was designed for a specific purpose: if you think using it for every day browsing is a good idea, you either have very specific needs... Or you're using it wrong.

(*removal* of original emphasis is mine; outside of the original context, it would have just looked unnecessarily harsh)

If it makes you feel any better, we're not working on implementing the request [Can SE block actions from Tor exit nodes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222386/can-se-block-actions-from-tor-exit-nodes) either.

Comment: The part of that answer quoted here is absolutely wrong.  There are a number of reasons to use Tor and using it for everyday browsing is a fine one: doing so can provide anonymity for the user and provides cover for other users who need that cover.

Comment: Most of the problem is due to Cloudflare, not this site specifically.  However, if this type of attitude (flippancy might be a good word) is indicative of the Tor SE management, then i question the reason for even having a Tor SE, or why i should use this.